# Reusing Line-Objects after saving a figure

Tags: matlab, save, matlab-figure, figure

Is there a way of reusing line objects to specify new properties after I saved a figure?
For example I'm defining this:

```
figure;
hold on;
line1 = line(linspace(0,2*pi,1000),sin(linspace(0,2*pi,1000)));
```

Now I will save this as `Sinus.fig` and when I open it later, I want to be able to do something like `set(line1,'LineWidth',2);`. Is there a way to achieve this or in General to change figures after saving them? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `appdata` which you embed in the figure are saved with it. It means you can use the [`guidata`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html) function to save all your graphic handles and then save them **with** the figure.
They will be available with the figure when you load it later on.

Exemple:
Generate the figure and graphic object, saving all handles which will need to be re-used:

```
%% // Generate figure and retrieve handles of graphic objects
h.fig = figure;
hold on;
h.line1 = line(linspace(0,2*pi,1000),sin(linspace(0,2*pi,1000)));
```

We have in the structure `h`:

```
>> h
h = 
      fig: [1x1 Figure]
    line1: [1x1 Line]
```

Now let's embed `h` into the figure then save it:

```
%% // Save
guidata( h.fig , h )        %// Save the handle information in the figure
saveas(h.fig,'sinus.fig')   %// Save the figure into file
clear all                   %// clear workspace
```

Now we can reload the figure any time, the structure `h` is still available in the application data of the figure (accessible with the same `guidata` function):

```
%% // Now re-open and load
f1 = openfig('C:\TEMP\sinus.fig') ; %// open the figure and retrieve the handle
h = guidata(f1) ;                   %// retrieve the full handle structure saved


set(h.line1,'LineWidth',2);         %// do what you want with your line/objects handles ;-)
```

---

Note that you could also use [`setappdata`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html) and [`getappdata`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getappdata.html) to save any variable that you may find useful with your figure. Look at their documentation for more info.

---

Answer (score 1):

You can use [findobj](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html) to extract particular objects from an open figure. In your case you want something like.

```
line1=getobject(gca, 'Type', 'line');
```

Be a bit careful if you have multiple lines in the figure as this will extract them all. If this is a problem you could either add extra arguments to only select the ones you want or use the line properties to separate them later.

Comment: If you go this way, I would recommend to assign a unique `tag` to each of the object you may want to retrieve. It will make finding the desired object easier and **unambiguous**. To assign a tag, just set the `Tag` property of the object, and to find the object later on, you can use: `line1=getobject(gcf, 'Tag', 'TheCustomTagDefinedForThisObject');`